# Inverse a cubic function

Tags: inverse-function, cubics

I've got this cubic function that I can't figure out how to calculate its inverse.

$$f(x)=x^3+3x^2+3x,  x\in \mathbb{R}$$

I've tried using online calculator to see if that would help, but none of them seemed to solve this.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+of+x%5E3%2B3x%5E2%2B3x wolfram alpha seems to find the inverse...

Comment: Hello, I was inactive for a while because of personal issues. I've marked the answer below as the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set $y=x^3+3x^2+3x$, and notice that $(x+1)^3=x^3+3x^2+3x+1 \implies y=(x+1)^3-1.$

Now we can just rearrange a bit (with a cube root thrown in there) to note $x=\sqrt[3]{y+1}-1.$

Thus, if  $f(x)=x^3+3x^2+3x,$  then $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt[3]{x+1}-1.$

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out.